# Printing GIF files from a browser

Tags: java, browser, applet, gif

We are currently leveraging a third party tool to convert pdf files into gifs and displaying them in the browser. We have been adjusting the DPI of these images so that when printed they will look as close as possible to what the original pdf looked like. We've found that at least a setting of 300 DPI matches roughly the clarity of what the pdf will display when printed. However if we try to load a GIF image with a setting of 300 DPI into the browser using HTML the image is very large and causes scrolling. I was able to get around it by setting the height and width of the image tag, however when/if the margins on the Print preferences changes the image will be chopped when printed. If we print the images as is through an image viewer they print fine.

So that leads me to my question, is there some other third party tool that we could call from a webpage that would load these images and give printing capabilities through some sort of a Java applet?

Comment: Why can't you display PDF files directly in the browser, using Adobe or Foxit plugins, as that's what almost everyone else does?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to embed the PDF file inside your HTML page, so if you print, you have full capatibilies, and you don't need to "duplicate" que information.
If you have to use GIF images (for any reason), you could have two views, one small, wihout scrolls, for viewing the HTML page, and other only with the GIF image. When you click "Print" in the HTML page, you see a kind of "Print preview", larger, with scrolls or whatever.

Hope it helps.